# How to setup a websocket with Javascript connected to Node-red

Tags: javascript, websocket, raspberry-pi, node-red

SO i have set myself with a project to turn on a light on RPi with node-red and a html document. So i have got all the node-red set up and it works along with the LED on my RPi. I installed apache2 and have been trying to start a websocket thing, but i have had no success.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
   <head>
      
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         function WebSocketTest() {
            
            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
               alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
               
               // Let us open a web socket
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://var/www/html/index.html");
                
               ws.onopen = function() {
                  
                  // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                  ws.send("Message to send");
                  alert("Message is sent...");
               };
                
               ws.onmessage = function (evt) { 
                  var received_msg = evt.data;
                  alert("Message is received...");
               };
                
               ws.onclose = function() { 
                  
                  // websocket is closed.
                  alert("Connection is closed..."); 
               };
            } else {
              
               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
         }
      </script>
        
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <div id = "sse">
         <a href = "javascript:WebSocketTest()" onclick="WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
      </div>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

this is my code, and i have been trying to get it to work for ages, so i have come to the conclusion that this is not going to work

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a file path for the websocket address.

It needs to be something like:

```
// Let us open a web socket
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://node-red.local:1880/foo");
```

Where Node-RED is running on `node-red.local` (you can probably swap this for the IP address) and you have configured a websocket-in node to bind to `/foo`

Comment: Thaks. But i dont know how it works with the '/foo' part of it, i have the new 'foo' node, but the only thing is i do not know what to do with it now

Comment: Attach a debug node to the websocket-in node and see what you get. You'll want a matching websocket-out node to reply

Comment: Yeah, i have done so, thanks, nothing is coming up